# jQuery form validation - phoneUS and default message style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am trying to create a form the requests a (US) phone number that is validated with the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).  Here are two examples.

1. [BEAUTIFUL error messages but DOESN'T validate the phone number](http://jsfiddle.net/h5xf2wdk/)
2. [PLAIN error messages but DOES validate the phone number](http://jsfiddle.net/muwmsbyx/1/)

They use the same HTML (see below).  The second one also uses some JavaScript (see below).

HTML

```
<form id="myform">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Phone Number</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Name" required="required" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="phoneUS" name="PhoneNumber" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    errorElement: 'div',
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});

});
```

I want both the beautiful error messages and validation of the phone number, but I can't figure out how to do that.  In fact, I don't even understand how the first one validates anything since no validation code is explicitly called.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: if you look at the External Resources tab of both JsFiddle examples you linked, you can see the links to external code used for the validation.

Comment: and the first example doesn't seem to work?

Comment: There is no such thing as an input of type "PhoneUS", so the browser will just treat it as a text input. There is however an input type="tel" - please see my answer below for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "beautiful" error messages are shown because of the `required="required"` attribute on the name input.

This is a standard HTML5 form validation attribute, and as such is handled entirely by the browser. As with so many things in life, your beautiful may not be the same as mine, depending on your browser.

Older browsers don't recognise it at all - http://caniuse.com/#search=form%20validation E.g. IE prior to 10.

There is also an `input type="tel"` for telephone numbers - and this is particularly good for mobile devices as it should show a numeric keyboard instead of the standard alpha one - but browser support is more limited:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url

The `tel` type also has a `pattern` attribute that accepts a regular expression for you to specify a particular phone number format: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html

But the long and the short of it is, if you need a consistent look to your error messages, and you need compatibility with older browsers then you'll need a Javascript based solution.

**Edit:** Updated your JSFiddle example using `input type="tel"` and what I believe to be a US phone No. pattern (nnn-nnn-nnnn): http://jsfiddle.net/h5xf2wdk/1/